# nested async.eachOfSeries TypeError: innerCallback is not a function

Tags: node.js

I am fairly new to javascript and have a bunch of synchronous code that I am trying to turn asynchrnous.  I have a library that has lots of data intensive for loops.  So far I have been able to easily convert the non-nested loops using the async library but I have run into a problem with nested loops.

When running the code below I get `TypeError: innerCallback is not a function`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Hopefully I am overlooking something small.

```
var async = require("async");

var byteArray = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
];

async.eachOfSeries(byteArray, function(bytes, x_index, outerCallback) {
    console.log(bytes);

    async.eachSeries(bytes, function(bits, y_index, innerCallback) {
        console.log(bits);
        innerCallback();
    });

    outerCallback();

}, function(err) {
    if (err) console.error(err.message);
});
```

Comment: Why not use `eachOfSeries` in the inner loop as well -> http://jsfiddle.net/edXs5/22/ ... for some reason the callback in `eachSeries` is the second argument

Comment: Wow!  That was my intention.  Thanks for pointing out what I had gone blind to!

Comment: It seems the documentation is somewhat mistaken, if you do `async.eachSeries(bytes, function(bits, innerCallback) {...` it works, yet the docs say the second argument is an iterator, and the third argument is the callback, but that seems to be only for `eachOfSeries`, for `eachSeries` the second argument is actually the callback

Comment: How do I select your comment as an answer?  I don't see any arrows or check boxes next to it.

Comment: I have to post it, which I've done !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use `eachOfSeries` in both the inner and outer iterations

```js
var byteArray = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
];

async.eachOfSeries(byteArray, function(bytes, x_index, outerCallback) {
    async.eachOfSeries(bytes, function(bits, y_index, innerCallback) {
        console.log(bits);
        innerCallback();
    });
 console.log('\n\n')
    outerCallback();

}, function(err) {
    if (err) console.error(err.message);
    console.log('done')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/async/2.1.2/async.js"></script>
```

Or you can keep on using `eachSeries` but it seems the [documentation](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries) is somewhat mistaken when it states that the arguments are

```
eachSeries(coll, iteratee, callback)
```

It seems it's actually

```
eachSeries(coll, callback)
```

making your code look like

```js
var byteArray = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
];

async.eachOfSeries(byteArray, function(bytes, x_index, outerCallback) {
 
    async.eachSeries(bytes, function(bits, innerCallback) {
        console.log(bits);
        innerCallback();
    });
 console.log('\n\n')
    outerCallback();

}, function(err) {
    if (err) console.error(err.message);
    console.log('done')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/async/2.1.2/async.js"></script>
```